# Removing the black block from the Data Studio Custom Visualisation

Tags: javascript, looker-studio

I am building a custom waterfall visualisation for a project at work- but really struggling against the documentation.

I have managed to get a CanvasJS graph tor render in Data Studio - but it also has some strange black square - which I am unable to get rid of.

How do I delete it?

[![blacksquare][1]][1]

I have used the visualisation code lab as the basis

Here is the code for my Visualisation

```
 var chartElement = document.createElement('div');
    chartElement.id = 'chartContainer';
    chartElement.style = "height: 300px; width: 100%;";
    document.body.appendChild(chartElement);
```

Comment: The black box drawn seems to be somewhere out of the chart and the code that you have shared seems to be working fine without any black boxes. Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/TX4BQzA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the black box was some sort of a cacheing glitch.  After I deleted the files and reuploaded to a new location in the bucket - it worked fine.

Thanks @vishwas R